apply: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, track-changes
Since I upgraded my emacs packages -- and in the process migrated to emacs 29.3 -- I've been seeing this error message:
apply: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, track-changes

or permutations of I cannot find track-changes.
I cannot for the life of me find this track-changes thing anywhere in my source code, my configs, and I could only find a mirror of a track-changes packages, but adding it didn't fix my troubles.
Annoyingly enough, trying to use emacs-lisp-mode fails with that message...
Could anyone provide some insight into this?

Do M-x toggle-debug-on-error and when you get a backtrace, edit your question and  add the backrace. Or if it happens at startup, start your emacs with emacs --debug-init.

Write to the author, who, as indicated in the file header, is "Stefan Monnier monnier@iro.umontreal.ca". That's user @Stefan, I believe.

@nickD set me on the right track. I started emacs with --debug-init and found immediately the offending library: parinfer-rust-mode.
I opened an issue at elpaca. It seems to be a problem with the library I used to keep my packages up to date.

@NickD it is an elpaca bug. Elpaca is an alternative package manager I use.

Ah, OK - my bad.
